# Scan local subnet for domain names

Tags: subnet

What is the best way to scan (using OS X, GUI/Terminal app), for ip's on a local subnet that have a domain name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to actually check if the hosts exist, is to just loop through the IP addresses and do a reverse lookup.  The following recipe works on Linux and FreeBSD; I don't know how the `host` program on Mac OS X behaves:

```
for x in $(seq 1 254); do
    host 10.0.0.$x || echo "no hostname for $x"
done
```

You can also use `nmap` to discover what hosts are up, do a reverse DNS lookup on the hosts that it finds, and then filter on that.  `nmap` has a bunch of options to fine tune the output, but perhaps start with

```
nmap -sP -R '10.0.0.*' -oN outfile
```

Or use `-oX` for XML output that you can process more deterministically.  Or combine it with a call to `host`.

Comment: nmap's default DNS resolution behavior is "sometimes", though I don't know how that's defined.  nmap -R forces to always resolve hostnames.

Comment: Thanks!  nmap + doing a host on the IP worked perfectly.